# Modifying styles of sub-elements for selected ListItems

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having some issue troubleshooting how to pass styles down to material UI components and modifying the styling of elements with active states. I'm currently following the example provided under the "Selectable List" option [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list).

I can modify some styles of the list active list item though the `selectedItemStyle` prop in the HOC but some styles are overridden. For example the color of the secondaryTextColor is overridden and I'm not sure how to override the default other than giving it a class and using `!important` which is not preferred. An example of my HOC is below.

```
import {List, makeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';
import { tealA700 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors'

let SelectableList = makeSelectable(List);

function wrapState(ComposedComponent) {
  return class SelectableList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
      defaultValue: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
      });
    }

    handleRequestChange = (event, index) => {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: index,
      });
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          value={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRequestChange}
          selectedItemStyle={{backgroundColor: tealA700, color: 'white', secondaryTextColor: 'white'}}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </ComposedComponent>
      );
    }
  };
}

SelectableList = wrapState(SelectableList);

export default SelectableList
```